# Python: How to do a system wide search for a file when just the filename (not path) is available

Tags: python, search

I'm still new to Python (using 2.6) and I am trying to do a system wide search for a file when just the filename is available and return the absolute path on windows. I've searched and found some modules like scriptutil.py and looked through the os module but haven't found anything that suits my needs (or I may not have understood everything correctly to apply it to what I need and thus have not included any code). I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The os.walk() function is one way of doing it.

```
import os
from os.path import join

lookfor = "python.exe"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
    print "searching", root
    if lookfor in files:
        print "found: %s" % join(root, lookfor)
        break
```

Comment: @ Martin Stone Yes it is, but it requires a path, or else is searches only the current working directory (if I understand correctly)

Comment: @ldmvcd, it searches recursively from the directory you tell it to start in.

Comment: @Martin Stone **break** should be removed, because there could be several files with the same name in different directories

Comment: @Martin Stone, thank you for the code, I guess you've already tried it, but for me the search is not successful. It seems to be only searching and listing directories and not the actual files. It thus does not find a match for the second print statement to print.

Comment: @Martin Stone, my apologies, I take that back. Your code does whats its supposed to be doing. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You could start at the **root** directory and recursively walk the directory structure looking at each level for the file. Of course if you want to search your entire system you will need to call this for each drive.

```
os.path.walk(rootdir,f,arg)
```

There's a good answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python) and another one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124810/how-can-i-find-path-to-given-file)

Comment: thank you for the links, they were helpful just like the answer posted above.

Comment: Using `os.path.walk`, which requires 3 arguments, has been deprecated since Python 2.3 (and removed entirely in 3.0) in favor of `os.walk`, which only requires 1 argument (and has 3 optional).

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
import os
import sys
import magic
import time
import fnmatch

class FileInfo(object):

    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.depth = filepath.strip('/').count('/')
        self.is_file = os.path.isfile(filepath)
        self.is_dir = os.path.isdir(filepath)
        self.is_link = os.path.islink(filepath)
        self.size = os.path.getsize(filepath)
        self.meta = magic.from_file(filepath).lower()
        self.mime = magic.from_file(filepath, mime=True)
        self.filepath = filepath


    def match(self, exp):
        return fnmatch.fnmatch(self.filepath, exp)

    def readfile(self):
        if self.is_file:
            with open(self.filepath, 'r') as _file:
                return _file.read()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)



def get_files(root):

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):

        for directory in dirs:
            for filename in directory:
                filename = os.path.join(root, filename)
                if os.path.isfile(filename) or os.path.isdir(filename):
                    yield FileInfo(filename)

        for filename in files:
            filename = os.path.join(root, filename)
            if os.path.isfile(filename) or os.path.isdir(filename):            
                yield FileInfo(filename)


for this in get_files('/home/ricky/Code/Python'):
    if this.match('*.py'):
        print this.filepath
```