# How do I get the path of a file I want to upload by a file entry?

Tags: python, path, appjar

I want to upload a file by a file entry and then when I click on "Save" I want to get the path of this selected file.

The next step would be to create either a `.txt` or a `yaml` file with this path in it as output.

Could someone help me with this?

```
win.addFileEntry("InputFile")
def press(button):
    if button == "Exit":
        win.stop()
    if button == "Save":
        print(path._getfullpathname(__file__))
        print("Saved!")

win.addButtons(["Add", "Remove", "Save", "Load", "Exit"], press)
```

Comment: Look up how can I find path to given file? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1124841/7583919

Answer (score 0):

You just need to ask the FileEntry for its contents:
`filename = win.getEntry('InputFile')`