# I want to make a program that takes file name from user and displays absolute path of the file

Tags: python, file, project

So what I basically am trying to make is a program that asks user for file and displays absolute path of the program. For eg. If user enters 'Spotify' then I want to locate spotify.exe on the pc if It exists and print its absolute path.

I wanted to make this for a personal assistant that I am working on.

I previously tried

`os.system(input + '.exe')`
but taking the eg of spotify only...it is not an internal file that will be recognised….please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use use `os.walk` to get the files's location and then `os.path.abspath` to get the full absolute pathname.

related answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1124841/2174832

Comment: I havent really studied os module so i dont know its features could you please explain walk's function a little. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

os.path.abspath(**file**)

Comment: no but i will try it now....for file do i need to give 'something.exe' or 'something'?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Linux, you can use os.system('which spotify')