# How do I find the path of a file using os.walk?

Tags: python, path

How do I find the path of a file? I know how to find the file but what about the path?

```
from PIL import Image
user_path = "/Users/" + getpass.getuser())

for folder, sub_folder, files in os.walk(user_path):
    for sub_fold in sub_folder:
        for f in files:
            if FileName == f:
                print("file found")
```

Comment: if you have the name of the file, you can just concatenate the directory path to the file, look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find path to given file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124810/how-can-i-find-path-to-given-file)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

os.walk yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames), where dirpath is the path of the current directory, meaning that you can just join with the filename:

```
from PIL import Image
user_path = "/Users/" + getpass.getuser())
for folder, sub_folders, files in os.walk(user_path):
    for f in files:
        if FileName == f:
            print("file found", os.path.join(folder,f))
```